# JS ecosystem - In which oder I should learn them?

Tags: javascript

I'm migrating from Java to JS and I would like to know what is the best way to do it in the field of JS ecosystem.

---

After reading all the [`You Don't Know JS`](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS) series by [Kyle Simpson](https://github.com/getify), I would like to learn: `npm`, `grunt`,`gulp`,`lint`, transpilers (`babel`), `webpack` and so on.

I don't have any experience in any of them and to be true, I bet I forgot to list some other tools.

---

What is the order which one should learn those tools? I will also love to know if there are tools that should be learned in a limited way *until* one has a better understanding of some other topics too.

Comment: Sorry, but this question is almost certainly going to be closed as primarily opinion based. Can you think of a way to rephrase it so that it is not?

Comment: Yes, I edited. It may be still opinion based but there is almost no other updated source which can answer this. To be short, I'm looking for a syllabus from more experienced javascript DevOps/ Engineers than me. There can't be too many answers to this because, for example, `npm` should learn first from this list.

Comment: Check out https://css-tricks.com/developer-roadmaps/. The items in this post cover more than just JS, but that may help you narrow down how and when to learn what in JavaScript land.